# Чи є різниця між словами "різний" і "відмінний"

Tags: різниця-між-словами

Я знайшов таке:

> - У лінгвістичному аспекті поняття «неоднаковий» означає «відмінний від іншого (інших), який не збігається з іншим (іншими); різний».
> - Синонімами поняття «різний» (у значенні «позбавлений схожості, однаковості») є «відмінний», «несхожий», «неоднаковий», «розбіжний».

Але до відповіді це мене не наблизило.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Повних синонімів не буває. Слово може містити у собі схожу семантичну картину, але відрізнятися за тим, з якими словами воно зазвичай комбінується (наприклад, можна зачинити двері і заплющити очі, але не можна заплющити двері і зачинити очі, якщо це тільки не високохудожнє вимахування) і в яких ситуаціях може вживатися.

Наприклад, слово "відмінний" не може замінити слово "різний" у таких випадках:

> — Який жанр літератури тобі подобається найбільше? – Мені подобаються **різні** жанри.
>
> — До свята ми приготували багато **різних** наїдків.
>
> — Для відповіді на це питання треба зважити **різні** аспекти.

Як бачимо, слово "різний" містить у собі [сему](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_(%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)) "бути одним з низки чогось" чи "становити низку". Зрозуміло, що елементи цієї низки відрізняються одне від одного, але не це основний сенс нашого повідомлення.

А от коли треба підкреслити саме те, що щось *відрізняється* від чогось, ми кажемо, що ці об'єкти *відмінні*.